# APNs/Firebase: when is it needed?

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I have a simple question related to APNs (Apple Push Notification service) and Firebase.
What I have read on the net does not give me a sure and clear answer.

I am using Firebase in an iOS app. When do I need to set APNs?
Precisely, if I am only using Database, Storage and possibly Authentication:
Do I need to set APNs?

I have read I should set up APNs when using Firebase Cloud Messaging, but that is not very clear.

Any precise information will be appreciated.

Comment: No need APNS for  Database, Storage and Authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APNs as you write is Apple Push Notification service, so you need to set it when you want firebase to send you push notification. In your case you have no need to set it, because I think there is no need for you to get push notifications, for Firebase Cloud Messaging exactly you need to set APNs to get push notifications when you got message, etc.

Answer (score 1):

APNS is not needed for database, storage and Auth.what u have read is right APNS is needed when you are working with cloud messaging.As there is no cloud messaging (Push notifications)so you will not be needing that.